# e2fsck block bitmaps

Tags: linux, partition, lvm, e2fsck

What exactly are block bitmaps? Why would I get the following error:

```
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 1219824640 blocks
The physical size of the device is 731447296 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Error reading block 731906048 (Invalid argument) while reading inode and block bitmaps.  Ignore error<y>? no
e2fsck: Can't read a block bitmap while retrying to read bitmaps for /dev/mapper/ops--vg--restore-root
```

This is my understanding of the way this works. I have a partition essentially, which is essentially an arbitrary point on the disk where the partition starts and ends. The problem that I am having is that the partition that believes it's size X is really size X-Y, so it ends up trying to read off the end of the LVM.

Is it possible to provide an arbitrary position and mount the partition anyway? If I'm incorrect would someone please explain it to me?